# ¿incognitas en c++?

Tags: c++

estaba pensando en hacer operaciones con variables matemáticas. Quería saber si existe algun método como el de sympy en python, en particular la función Symbol:

```py
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol("x")

print(x + 1)
```

```py
x + 1
```

Si no hay manera de hacer esto, ¿podrían darme un consejo de como hacerlo?

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías usar un contenedor [std::map](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Answer (score 2):

> quería saber si existe algun método como el de sympy en python, en particular la función Symbol

No.

---

> Si no hay manera de hacer esto, ¿podrían darme un consejo de como hacerlo?

Podrías usar literales definidos por el usuario:

```
std::map<std::string, double> incognitas;

double &operator ""_incognita(const char *nombre, size_t)
{
    auto [i, b] = incognitas.emplace(nombre, .0);
    return i->second;
}
```

Con ese literal, el siguiente código:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "x"_incognita << '\n';

    "x"_incognita = 100;

    std::cout << "x"_incognita + 1 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Muestra:

> ```
> 0
> 101
> ```

La versión C++11 del literal definido por el usuario sería:

```
double &operator ""_incognita(const char *nombre, size_t)
{
    auto r = incognitas.emplace(nombre, .0);
    return r.first->second;
}
```